# Bulk - registration in phpbb forum

Tags: php, phpbb

Is bulk registration possible in phpbb forum. I want to add more than 1 user at a time from the admin control panel. Is any plugins already available for this? Or is any other way to implement this feature??

Answer (score 0):

Here you can research more about:

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=1252845#p7446275

Comment: It's seems like we have to do if from our system. But when a client adding something directly from the administrator side it won't be helpful!!